# I need to get multiple complex sets of data into Javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have a database that I'm trying to display reports on using the Highcharts javascript library.

The issue is i have no idea how to effectively get this data from Rails into Javascript.

Simply using html data attributes doesnt scale because i have many charts and many different sets of data for each one. I need to exclude certain columns, join tables, etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: Aggregate the data and display different charts with different aggregations.

Comment: Make xhr request in your JS for this data and send them from Rails as JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Several options are available:

1. Create instance variables and pass them into the html template using **gon**

https://github.com/gazay/gon

2. Create an endpoint and format the data using ActiveModelSerializers, eg: https://www.engineyard.com/blog/active-model-serializers
3. You could create a **jbuilder** view and render it via an endpoint called by a javascript ajax call

https://github.com/rails/jbuilder

Lowest effort is **Gon**, but everything you send into it is viewable in the HTML source.